# Double post notices are possible if submitted at nearly the same time

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, post-notices

It appears possible that post notices can show up twice if moderators add them to the post at roughly the same time (in this case, it was only about 3 seconds apart from the edit history):

[image]

If I revisit the mod menu, I can remove the post notice and it removes both, then I can re-add it as needed. Not sure if it needs to be addressed as it's probably infrequent enough, but it might be a sign there are other race conditions possible for simultaneous edits to posts.

Comment: Identical bug previously reported on Meta Stack Overflow: [Two moderators can overlap lock messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403298/two-moderators-can-overlap-lock-messages)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This bug is now fixed.